# Restarting apache from PHP

Tags: php, apache, restart

I know that there are a lot of similar questions already on the website or even in the another ones but I didn't get the solution even looking for all the information of this questions.

From PHP code, I'm trying:

```
exec('/etc/init.d/apache2 restart');
```

And on my sudoers file, I added the following line:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I tried a lot of combinations here like for exaple creating Cmnd_Alias but nothing works.

If I execute this exec, I get "**Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service failed!**". And If I execute this exec command but with sudo, I get an error "**Failed to restart apache2.service: Interactive authentication required.**" (seen on apache error.log). I have seen this error from browser console because I'm running the code from an AJAX post.

But if I try from the cmd, this command ask for a password (I don't understand why if I added the line I explained before on sudoers file):

```
sudo -u www-data /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And of course if I add sudo, it works:

```
sudo -u www-data sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

So I really don't know what is wrong here. If someone can help I will appreciate it because I am quite lost...

Regards

Comment: Why don't you use sudo in your command? `exec('sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart');`

Comment: @Markus Zeller like I wrote, "If I execute this exec command but with sudo, I get an error "Failed to restart apache2.service: Interactive authentication required."

Comment: You need sudo to do that, except for you are the root user. There's also no need to use `-u www-data`, because the current user will be elevated to root access. Try the service command like `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Comment: @Markus Zeller I know there is no need to it, but I just did it to test. I also tried sudo service apache2 reload, but I can't write the sudo on the exec order or I get the error. So the same thing happens

Comment: Stopped from terminal via `sudo service apache2 stop`. Then run index.php containing `exec('sudo apachectl restart');` worked for me. `sudo service apache2 status` said 'apache2 is running'.

Comment: How should I run this index.php file if apache2 is stopped?

Comment: I did from terminal of course. This was just a test, if a restart from a php script will work. If you concern about that, you also should use `graceful` instead of reload. Notice, that apachectl is used instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222734/discussion-between-daniel-r-and-markus-zeller).